# Firewall blocking backups

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, firewall, backupexec, symantec

I currently have two database servers (SQLMS) and two web servers (IIS) that host several websites. Between the two sets of servers lies a PIX firewall unit. I am fairly new to the company and am very limited on the configuration of the network within these servers and firewall.

The task I have been presented with is to backup all of the servers to a Quantum tape drive that is connected to one of the SQL servers. On that server I am using Symantec Backup Exec to run the backup processes. It successfully backs up the data on the SQL servers but cannot access the data needed from the IIS servers. I am 99.9% sure the issue is established at the firewall (Firewall is blocking communication between servers or  blocking the software). I can successfully ping the servers through the firewall but no data transmission is allowed.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or what to look for within the firewall to allow the "unblocking" of communication of the program to backup the data?

**All four servers are running Windows 2008 R2**

Comment: I'm assuming your IIS server is outside your LAN? Are you getting any messages in the logs for Symantec?

Comment: MY IIS server is still within the LAN, I just have a firewall implemented between the servers for extra security. And I get the following error from my logs...

Comment: Completed status: Failed
Final error: 0xe000810c - Physical Volume Library not available.
Final error category: Backup Device Errors

For additional information regarding this error refer to link [V-79-57344-33036](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=answers&startover=y&question_box=V-79-57344-33036)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [pretty thorough list of ports](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH49563) that backup exec uses. You might want to forward that to the group that can set that up for you. I would probably start with port 10000, that should fix the issue with the V-79-57344-33036 error.